# Plotting multiple spectra on ggplot gives a strange plot with vertical lines joining y-values to each x-value instead of single y-values per x-value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot multiple spectra on ggplot. Each spectra should be a separate line, but it is doing something strange and joining y-values at each x-value instead of joining across x-values.

My data is in long format;

> ```
>      V1       Sample_ID wavenumber transmittance 
>   1 Crete         1       1328       1180708 
>   2 Crete         1       1330       1180866 
>   3 Crete         1       1332       1181083 
>   4 Crete         1       1334       1181379
> ```

and I used the below code to plot the spectra:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = wavenumber, y = transmittance, color = Sample_ID)) + geom_line()
```

[image: Spectra plot]

The plot should be lots of lines (Each Sample_ID) stacked on top of eachother...

Comment: Try adding `group = Sample_ID` inside the `aes()` call.

Comment: What is the type of you wavenumber column I suspect that is is a factor/character and not a numeric and this is the source of the error.

Comment: @JonSpring that seems to have done it.

Comment: @RichardJ.Acton it now seems to plot OK with Jon's suggestion. I have a follow up because I tried your version too, and when I used as.numeric, the factor became 1,2,... when it was 1328, 1330, ... - do you know how I would change it to a numeric vector whilst retaining that numerical value rather than 1,2,...?

Comment: Try `aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(wavenumber)), ...` to first extract the labels of the factor levels and then convert them to numbers. Should allow the x-axis to be continuous, with correct numerical scaling.

Comment: Factors have a numeric vector with a number for each level as well as levels with a mapping between the names of the levels and their numeric representation. So when the levels of a factor are numeric you can convert it to a character vector first. `as.numeric(as.character(yourFactor))`, or alternatively and more computationally efficiently you can use `as.numeric(levels(yourFactor))[yourFactor]`